# error: invalid path 'filePath:Zone.Identifier'

Tags: git

If I try to check out the **development** branch, I am getting this error:

```
$ git checkout development
error: invalid path 'src/assets/svg-icon/exit.svg:Zone.Identifier'
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this? I am using windows-10.

Answer (score 10):

I faced same issue while cloning the project.
Resolved this issue by understanding why this happened with help of this page
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777

then run this command to set the flag

`git config core.protectNTFS false`

Above command require Admin permission to update flag

To run this command as administrator open terminal(cmd prompt) as admin and run below mentioned command

`git config --system core.protectNTFS false`

For more detailed information you can go through this page

[github/git Checkout Returns 'error: invalid path' on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727594/github-git-checkout-returns-error-invalid-path-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

[Issue 2777](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2777#issuecomment-1368210010) does add:

> this is indeed an invalid path.
>
> The `:Zone.Identifier` suffix is a so-called "**Alternate Data Stream**" (see e.g. [this blog post](https://davidhamann.de/2019/02/23/hidden-in-plain-sight-alternate-data-streams/) for more information) that is attached to the file in question, and **it is not supposed to be committed**, and it is certainly not supposed to be checked out.
>
> You need to remove this before checking out (e.g. by cloning with `--no-checkout` and then playing games with the Git index all while operating under `core.protectNTFS=false`).

The blog post: "[Hidden in plain sight: Alternate Data Streams](https://davidhamann.de/2019/02/23/hidden-in-plain-sight-alternate-data-streams/)" from [David Hamann](https://twitter.com/d_hamann).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a useless file. In my workflow file I delete it after building and then everything worked.