# Cannot check out new branch because of invalid path?

Tags: windows, git, github, terminal, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a repo to my computer. I do the standard

```
git clone [link to bitbucket repo]
```

and then call

```
git branch -a
```

to see my remote branches, which shows

```
remotes/origin/develop
```

which is the branch I want to checkout into. However, when I type

```
git checkout develop
```

I get an error that says

```
error: invalid path '.\api-log\api.log'
```

and it fails to create the local develop branch. Is this happening because there is something wrong with the file? If so, how can I fix/remove the file so that the clone will go through? All the work is in the develop branch and nothing in the master.

I'm using Windows.

Apologies if this has been answered before but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What was that random file in the repo?

Comment: @Schwern  .\api-log\api.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github/git Checkout Returns 'error: invalid path' on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727594/github-git-checkout-returns-error-invalid-path-on-windows)

Comment: @Kraigolas I don't think so, I don't think there's any problem with the filename like a : or aux...But I did run the git config that post suggested and it didn't change anything.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why Windows thinks that's an invalid path, but I don't use Windows. The murky suspicion I have is that the path contains literal backslash characters as part of a file name, and Windows cannot handle that. You would have to examine the commit directly (`git ls-tree -r`) and/or Git's index (`git ls-files`) to confirm this.

Comment: Whatever the case may be, Git *can* deal with the repository; it's just that *Windows* cannot extract the files using the names that are listed in the repository. This is painful to deal with, with the one rare exception: if you can just *delete* the file with the bad name, use `git rm --cached` to do that, and then commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this happen but I suggest you to remove the offending file from the repository history by the wonderful BFG tool.

At this url https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ you can get the software and the documentation.