# Git clone is not working due to bad file path

Tags: windows, git, github, sparse-checkout

#### Problem

Git cloning the repository on a Windows 10 machine throws this error:

> error: invalid path 'saleor/graphql/core/tests/cassettes/test_get_oembed_data[http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ-VIDEO].yaml'
>
> fatal: unable to checkout working tree
>
> warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.

```
>git clone https://github.com/mirumee/saleor.git
Cloning into 'saleor'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 187180, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (289/289), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
remote: Total 187180 (delta 136), reused 131 (delta 64), pack-reused 186891
Receiving objects: 100% (187180/187180), 105.28 MiB | 234.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (137187/137187), done.
error: invalid path 'saleor/graphql/core/tests/cassettes/test_get_oembed_data[http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ-VIDEO].yaml'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

#### Tried

I tried [this](https://brendanforster.com/notes/fixing-invalid-git-paths-on-windows/) approach but it didn't work at the last step:

```
$ git init saleor
$ cd saleor
$ git remote add origin https://gitzzz.com/yyy/saleor.git -f
```

So far so good, but this command throws error:

```
$ git checkout origin/master -f
error: invalid path 'saleor/graphql/core/tests/cassettes/test_get_oembed_data[http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ-VIDEO].yaml'
```

#### Tried

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63742773/3405291) approach didn't help.

#### Question

How can I clone/checkout this repo on Windows?

#### Solution

The option suggested by @bk2204 resolved the issue:

1. Fork the repository
2. Clone the fork on Linux
3. Change the path names on Linux
4. Commit and push
5. Then check out the fixed fork on Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the path contains both colons and question marks and you're likely on a Windows system.  Windows has made a deliberate decision not to allow these characters in path names, so there's no way to check this file out there.

You have some options:

- Use a different operating system, like macOS or Linux.
- Check the file out using the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which doesn't suffer from these limitations.
- Ask the party responsible for the repository to change the path name or do it yourself in another environment, then check out the fixed repo.
- Ask Microsoft to fix this problem.
- Don't use this repo.

Comment: Alright =) But is there a way to change the bad file paths inside the `.git` directory? Something like hacking the `.git` folder?

Comment: I'm going to try this suggestion: `... to change the path name ... in another environment, then check out the fixed repo.`