# Git Erro when I want change the branch

Tags: gitlab, branch

when I want change of branch, and it throw me this error

`git checkout remote_branch`

`error: invalid path 'reportes/Interfaces/\exp\dos.xls'`

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727594/github-git-checkout-returns-error-invalid-path-on-windows ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I can't resolve it