# Delete files/directories matching a pattern buried in possibly several commits in a repo

Tags: git, windows-10, git-checkout, wsl-2

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63727594/595305), and my comment at the bottom of the question.

I have just cloned a repo in a Windows 10 OS which I developed in Linux, and git won't let me check to a branch because elements in it have paths which are illegal in Windows. To work around this I have checked out the branch concerned in WSL.

But what I want to do is delete all elements matching a pattern in all commits in a given branch (or indeed throughout the entire repo). Is there any way to do that?

This is the error I got in W10 (i.e. before going into WSL):

```
D:\My documents\doc_indexer>git checkout br_2022_01_16
error: invalid path 'D:\temp\logging/doc_indexer/.__rotator_fh.lock'
error: invalid path 'D:\temp\logging/doc_indexer/rotator_fh.log.1'
```

These paths are illegal in Windows not least because they contain a ":". These two files are not showing in WSL as part of the commit on the checked out branch ... and are therefore in older commits in this branch.

How might I weed them out and destroy them? If this is very hard or impossible, is there something else I might do so I can check out this branch in W10 "normal"?

***Answers to comment questions***

`git ls-tree -r br_2022_01_16` : yes, those blobs are listed there...

`git rev-parse --show-toplevel` : this shows the root directory, i.e. the one containing dir ".git".

Comment: Do they show up if you run `git ls-tree -r br_2022_01_16`?

Comment: where is the root of your repository located ? `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

Comment: see answers. does their presence in the `ls-tree` command mean something about their deletability?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to delete files from all commits. This operation can be destructive, it is a good idea to make a backup of your repo before running it.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch files to delete' --all
```

There's also [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which is a newer alternative to filter-branch:

```
git filter-repo --path files --path to --path delete --invert-paths
```

Depending on your exact use case, `--path-regex`, `--path-glob`, or `--paths-from-file` might give you better user experience.