# Cannot clone git repo due to invalid path, however path has no invalid characters

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I'm trying to clone my own private git repo onto another computer.

It will not finish cloning, and gives me an error message saying "Cannot checkout to invalid path frontend/src/pages/subjects/SubstrateCulturesOverview.tsx"

From searching online the only reason seems to be invalid chars, but nothing in the name seems off. I can't see any invalid char.

Comment: Do any of the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727594/github-git-checkout-returns-error-invalid-path-on-windows) work? Do you have WSL to test on, or Unix-like OS, to see if it's an issue in the repo or just with Windows? Have you double-checked that there are no hidden or [troll](https://github.com/vim-utils/vim-troll-stopper) unicode characters in that path?

Comment: OH MY GOD THERE WAS A SPACE AFTER THE FILE TYPE
I've been tearing my hair out. 
It was literally invisible

Comment: Depending on your editor, you can probably configure things to warn you. I use Vim with the troll-stopper and trailing-whitespace plugins, but I would bet most other editors have something similar. Saves a lot of time on these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - found a space char after the end of the filetype.
Windows couldn't handle it. Linux masterrace I guess